# Raspberry Pi DC motor speed web server

Tags: html, raspberry-pi, webserver

I am trying to control a robot car (with two DC motors) through a web server on the raspberry. I want to slow it down though... And I have no idea how to do this.
I also have a program for it to run by itself (not over a web server) (the line following robot car, if you know this), and there I used:

```
int softPwmCreate (int pin, int initialValue, int pwmRange) ;

void softPwmWrite (int pin, int value) ;
```

Got it from [here](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/software-pwm-library/)

This works great! But, of course, this doesn't work on the web server
I really have no idea how to do this, and I am relatively new to all of this, so I hope you can help me out

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method=GET action="sumo1.php">
<input name="button" type="submit" value="&#8593;"> <!--  ↑  -->
<input name="button" type="submit" value="&#8595;"> <!--  ↓  -->
<input name="button" type="submit" value="&#8592;"> <!--  ←  -->
<input name="button" type="submit" value="&#8594;"> <!--  →  -->
<input name="button" type="submit" value="STOP"> 

</form>

<?php
system("gpio mode 0 output");
system("gpio mode 1 output");
system("gpio mode 6 output");
system("gpio mode 2 output");
system("gpio mode 3 output");
system("gpio mode 4 output");
system("gpio mode 5 output");
system("gpio mode 4 output");
system("gpio mode 5 output");

system("gpio write 0 1");
system("gpio write 1 1");
system("gpio write 6 1");

if ($_GET["button"] == "&#8593;") //Forward
{
system("gpio write 2 1");
system("gpio write 3 0");
system("gpio write 4 1");
system("gpio write 5 0");
};

if ($_GET["button"] == "&#8595;") //Backwards
{
system("gpio write 2 0");
system("gpio write 3 1");
system("gpio write 4 0");
system("gpio write 5 1");

};

if ($_GET["button"] == "&#8592;") //Left
{
system("gpio write 2 1");
system("gpio write 3 0");
system("gpio write 4 0");
system("gpio write 5 1");

};

if ($_GET["button"] == "&#8594;") //Right
{
system("gpio write 2 0");
system("gpio write 3 1");
system("gpio write 4 1");
system("gpio write 5 0");

};

if ($_GET["button"] == "STOP") //Stop
{
system("gpio write 2 0");
system("gpio write 3 0");
system("gpio write 4 0");
system("gpio write 5 0");
};


?>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Can you tell us how you're calling this via webserver ?

Comment: @dastaan I added the code to my question  :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. Your existing code works fine (with system gpio calling) and now you want to add pwm support so that you can control speed ? If that's the case, you can have a look at this link --> https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/the-gpio-utility/ and have a look at pwm commands in gpio library.

Comment: I don't need to be able to control the speed. I just want it to go slower in general. With the speed it's going now, it's impossible to control.

Comment: May be you can write a custom python script which takes start / stop, speed and direction as the argument (from a file) and run in default stop situation at the start up and then you can alter that config file to change all those parameters. Not sure if it's a good work around but it should work. As far as, speed implantation of this goes, you can have start / stop time in a second to create a virtual pwm effect to control speed.